# XsltListViewWebpart does not display calendar control

Tags: sharepoint-server, web-part, page-layout, 2016

I have a custom Pagelayout, I wan't to add a EventList and will show the Calendar View for this.

But when I use the follwing code in the custom pagelayout it only show a plain list.

```
<WebPartPages:XsltListViewWebPart ID="calendarmaintenance" runat="server" ListUrl="Lists/ServiceCalendar" IsIncluded="True" NoDefaultStyle="TRUE" Title="Public Documents" PageType="PAGE_NORMALVIEW" FrameType="None" Default="False" ViewContentTypeId="0x">
    <XmlDefinition>
        <View BaseViewID="2" Type="CALENDAR" WebPartZoneID="Main" DisplayName="$Resources:core,userinfo_schema_calendarview;" MobileView="TRUE" MobileDefaultView="TRUE" 
            SetupPath="pages\viewpage.aspx" ImageUrl="/_layouts/15/images/events.png?rev=23" TabularView="FALSE" Url="calendar.aspx" RecurrenceRowset="TRUE" DefaultView="TRUE" 
            MobileUrl="_layouts/15/mobile/viewdaily.aspx">
            <Toolbar Type="None" />
            <ParameterBindings>
                <ParameterBinding Name="NoAnnouncements" Location="Resource(wss,noXinviewofY_LIST)" />
                <ParameterBinding Name="NoAnnouncementsHowTo" Location="Resource(wss,noXinviewofY_DEFAULT)" />
            </ParameterBindings>
            <ViewFields>
            </ViewFields>
            <ViewData>
                <FieldRef Name="Location" Type="CalendarWeekLocation"/>
                <Query>
                </Query>
            </View>
        </XmlDefinition>

    </WebPartPages:XsltListViewWebPart>
```

I also Tried to adding a ListViewWebpart onto the Page in a webpart zone with follwing code:

```
   ListViewWebPart calendar = new ListViewWebPart();
calendar.ListId = list.ID;
foreach (SPView view in list.Views)
{
    if (view.Url.ToString().Contains(urlviewpagename))
    {
        SharePointLogger.Log($"Found view {urlviewpagename}");
        calendar.ID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("B").ToUpperInvariant();
        calendar.ViewGuid = view.ID.ToString("B").ToUpperInvariant();
    }
}
calendar.ChromeState = PartChromeState.Normal;
calendar.ChromeType = PartChromeType.TitleOnly;
SharePointLogger.LogInformation($"Adding {list.Title} to zone {zoneid}");
webpartManager.AddWebPart(calendar, zoneid, 0);
```

This dispaly the Calendar but it does throw many javascript exceptions and I also have a deactivated ribbon bar to. What do I wrong? :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved my problem. I used a guid with dashes and this won't work. I replaced this wit Guid.ToString("n") tomged a guid without dashes and after that it worked well.